Completeness using nested intervals theorem not sure what I did is correct
Let $X$ be a metric space in which you know that for every sequence of closed nested subsets $A_{n}$, the diameter tends to $0$, and the intersection is non-empty. I need to prove that $X$ is complete.
I used the approach of creating a sequence of closed balls with $\mathrm{diam(A_{n}}) \to 0 $, but I centered every ball on $x$, with $x$ being the limit of an arbitrary Cauchy sequence, and inside every ball, there was an element of the sequence, as there is one as close to one chooses from each other so that in the end I was left with $x$ being the only possible element on the intersection and then, for the assumption of it being non-empty to be true, it was necessary that $x$ belonged to $X$. Is it completely wrong because I centered every ball on an element? I don't know whether it is in the space or not.

In principle, you can work with the completion of $X$. There the limit exists. But you have to intersect the closed subsets with $X$.

Your supposition that you cannot do that is correct -- by centering the ball on the supposed limit $x$, you are assuming that the limit is an element of $X$ -- but if you know that each Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a limit in $X$, then you already know that $X$ is complete.
So, you'll need to start with an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ and show that its limit exists (and it will in fact be the point common to all of the nested balls -- but you'll have to prove this fact).

As you mentioned, you can't center a ball on a point you don't even know it belongs to $X$.
By the way, according to how the question is formulated, every closed subset $C\subseteq X$ has diameter equal to $0$, since you can consider the constant sequence $A_n=C$ $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ (which is a valid sequence of closed and nested subsets of $X$). In my opinion, the correct formulation would be:
Let $X$ be a metric space in which for every sequence of closed and nested subsets $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $X$ such that diam$(A_n)\rightarrow 0$ we have $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\neq\emptyset$. Prove that $X$ is complete.
Here's my approach:
Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Define $A_n:=\overline{\{x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots\}}$ $\forall n\in\mathbb N$. This is obviously a family of nested closed subsets of $X$. Moreover, since the diameter of a set is unaffected by closures, we have
$$\operatorname{diam}(A_n)=\operatorname{diam}(\{x_n,x_{n+1},\dots\})=\sup_{k\ge n}d(x_k,x_n)=\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}d(x_{n+k},x_n);$$
This quantity goes to zero as $n\to+\infty$ thanks to the fact that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. By our hypothesis, these exists $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$. We aim to prove that $x_n\to x$, so fix $\epsilon>0$.
(1.) $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ $x\in A_n=\overline{\{x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots\}}$, so $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ we have $\mathbb D(x,\frac{\epsilon}{2})\cap\{x_n,x_{n+1},\dots\}\neq\emptyset$ (here $\mathbb D(y,r)$ denotes the open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r$), meaning that $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ $\exists k_n\ge n$ such that $d(x,x_{k_n})<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
(2.) Since $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy, there exists some $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $m,n\ge N_\epsilon$ one has $d(x_n,x_m)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
Then, for all $n\ge N_\epsilon$,
$$d(x,x_n)\le d(x,x_{k_{N_\epsilon}})+d(x_{k_{N_\epsilon}},x_n)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
By virtue of the fact that (1.) $d(x,x_{k_{N_\epsilon}})<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and (2.) $d(x_{k_{N_\epsilon}},x_n)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (notice that both $n\ge N_\epsilon$ and $k_{N_{\epsilon}}\ge N_{\epsilon}$).
